# BCD adder in Verilog (with gates)

Tags: logic, verilog, hdl, bcd

My goal is coding a BCD adder in Verilog with gates. I have some issues:

1- How can I select bits from first "four bit adders" outputs. My sum is `S`.  After I used `S` in first adder, can I select bits like `S[0]` or is there another way?

2- How can I specify inputs, especially if I have a module for `four_bit_adder` and it takes one element like `A` (4 bits)?  I tried to specify some bits, but I couldn't handle it.

For example, `A[3]` and `A[1]` needed to be 0 or 1 regarding the some situations, but my module takes one element.

My trial is below:

```
`include "four_bit_adder.v"

module bcd_adder(S,A,B,Cin);

input [3:0]A,B;
input Cin;
output [3:0]S;

wire [2:0]connectors;

//four_bit_adder(S,Cout,A,B,Cin);

four_bit_adder F_A1(S,Cout,A,B,Cin);

and(connectors[0],S[3],S[2]);

and(connectors[1],S[3],S[1]);

or(connectors[2],connectors[1],connectors[0],Cout);

//four_bit_adder F_A2();

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `Cout` output to your `bcd_adder`, driven by your `or` gate.  I changed `connectors` to `[1:0]`.

I created a wire for the binary sum (`sumb`), driven by your 1st 4-bit adder.  This is different from your BCD sum `S`.  `sumb` is connected to the `A` input of the 2nd 4-bit adder.

For the `B` input to the 2nd adder, I concatenate 4 bits like this:

```
{1'b0,Cout,Cout,1'b0}
```

Here is the completed module:

```vhdl
module bcd_adder(S,Cout,A,B,Cin);

input [3:0]A,B;
input Cin;
output [3:0]S;
output Cout;

wire [1:0]connectors;
wire [3:0]sumb;
wire coutb;
wire cout2; // floating

four_bit_adder F_A1 (sumb,coutb,A,B,Cin);
four_bit_adder F_A2 (S,cout2,sumb,{1'b0,Cout,Cout,1'b0},1'b0);

and(connectors[0],sumb[3],sumb[2]);
and(connectors[1],sumb[3],sumb[1]);
or (Cout,connectors[1],connectors[0],coutb);

endmodule
```